# A: Get notified of changes to the azure devops service

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've been looking around for a while now but I can't seem to find a way to get push messages from the azure devops team for their release notes regarding the azure devops service. I would like to be able to incorporate the changes/release notes into a teams channel (the app). I was surprised by a change to the `GET git repo list api url`. Which broke some stuff.

I can't really find any way to subscribe to changes to their service, other then to watch the ms-documentation github repo.

What are the ways in which you make sure you are not surprised by breaking changes?

Comment: The releases notes of Azure DevOps service is posted in the documentation: [Azure DevOps Feature Timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline), and you need to monitor it because there are no such provided subscriptions. BTW, does ```GET git repo list api url``` mean [Github Repo List](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos)? If yes, you could submit it here: [GitHub Support Community](https://github.community/) to as for professional support.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing this API: [Repositories - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), we can still retrieve git repositories under this project.
In addition, [sprint-184-update for Azure DevOps service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-184-update#azure-repos-1) brings new feature: `Disable a repository`.
[image]

And by reference to this doc: [Build Azure Repos Git or TFS Git repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#limit-job-authorization-scope-to-referenced-azure-devops-repositories), Azure DevOps enables some limitation to Azure Pipelines regarding to Azure Repos Git repository like `Limit job authorization scope to referenced Azure DevOps repositories`. Please check it.

[image]

**Update**>>This API: `GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1` does the same thing to retrieve git repositories.

And Azure DevOps service doesn't provide notifications about repositories changes(Add, Delete), see: [Supported subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops#supported-subscriptions) for details. Also currently official released APIs list here: [Azure DevOps Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

BTW, you can create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. We still had `-preview` appended to the url. The question is not about how to retrieve the api call but about being notified about changes. It seems the only way to do this is by reading the azure devops blog.

Comment: This API: ```GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1``` does the same thing to retrieve git repositories. And Azure DevOps service doesn't provide notifications about repositories changes(Add, Delete). Currently official released APIs list here: [Azure DevOps Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

Comment: Guess this is the solution then. They don't provide update changes. Best way of knowing is probably reading the azure devops blog.

Comment: Yeah, you could also submit your feedback [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion), so it will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions. Thanks for providing valuable feedback to help improve the product.